# MySQL Workbench for OSX. No utilities available

Tags: mysql, macos, mysql-workbench

I'm trying get MySQL and Workbench running on my Mac.

Workbench installed just fine, but when I try to run MySQL utilities, I get an error saying that "The command line MySQL utilities could not be located".

[image: Can't locate utilities]

But when I go to the download page, there is no version available for Mac.

[image: Utilities doesn't exist]

I have already installed MySQL community server by using the .dmg installer.

Please help, anyone who has installed MySQL workbench on a Mac recently.

(P.S. - I'm running OSX 10.9, if it matters).

Thanks!

Comment: When posting images captured on a MBP w/ Retina display, better shrink them by 50% first ;-)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You **have to build it and install** from source code

1. **[Download](http://dev.mysql.com/get/Downloads/Connector-Python/mysql-connector-python-1.0.12.tar.gz)** (Linux - Generic) and **[install](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-installation-source-unix.html)** Connector/Python first

   ```
   $ tar -xvf mysql-connector-python-1.0.12.tar.gz
   $ cd mysql-connector-python-1.0.12
   $ sudo python setup.py install
   ```
2. **[Download](http://dev.mysql.com/get/Downloads/MySQLGUITools/mysql-utilities-1.3.5.tar.gz)** (Platform Independent) and **[install](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/mysql-utils-install-source.html)** MySQL Utilities

   ```
   $ tar -xvf mysql-utilities-1.3.5.tar.gz 
   $ cd mysql-utilities-1.3.5/
   $ python ./setup.py build
   $ sudo python ./setup.py install
   ```

And voila you get yourself MySQL Utilities

```
$ /usr/local/bin/mysqluc -e "help utilities"
Launching console ...

Utility           Description                                              
----------------  ---------------------------------------------------------
mysqlauditadmin   audit log maintenance utility                            
mysqlauditgrep    audit log search utility                                 
mysqldbcompare    compare databases for consistency                        
mysqldbcopy       copy databases from one server to another                
mysqldbexport     export metadata and data from databases                  
mysqldbimport     import metadata and data from files                      
mysqldiff         compare object definitions among objects where the       
                  difference is how db1.obj1 differs from db2.obj2         
mysqldiskusage    show disk usage for databases                            
mysqlfailover     automatic replication health monitoring and failover     
mysqlfrm          show CREATE TABLE from .frm files                        
mysqlindexcheck   check for duplicate or redundant indexes                 
mysqlmetagrep     search metadata                                          
mysqlprocgrep     search process information                               
mysqlreplicate    establish replication with a master                      
mysqlrpladmin     administration utility for MySQL replication             
mysqlrplcheck     check replication                                        
mysqlrplshow      show slaves attached to a master                         
mysqlserverclone  start another instance of a running server               
mysqlserverinfo   show server information                                  
mysqluserclone    clone a MySQL user account to one or more new users
```

Answer (score 1):

The utilities are available now for Mac OS 10.6 (under previous GA versions) to 10.9:

http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/utilities/